# Would it be possible in Access to show the name of the user who has made changes in the report or the data in the access database

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Would it be possible in Access to show the name of the user who has logged in to the application and made changes in the report or the data in the access database.
For e.g.

I have a table with more than 1 users in the access application used for storing and editing data.

-User ABC logs in to the application edits the data / records in the table
-User DEF and other users should be able to see the name of the user who has changed the table records .viz. user abc's name in the table record column name "modified by" and "modified date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can receive OS user name using function

```
Environ("username")
```

Create a table with real user names and their OS user names and show to others real name instead of OS.

If you use custom login form with internal application users, just use application user name/ID

Store OS or application user name in ModifiedBy field of your data tables in `AfterUpdate` form event.

You can update this field automatically if you create a Data Macro for table with data. Data Macro was introduced in Access 2010, this is not regular macro, use table designer for editing data macroses. Create Before Change data macro:

```
SetField
    Name  ModifiedDate
    Value Now()
SetField
    Name  ModifiedBy
    Value GetFullUserInfo()
```

Here `GetFullUserInfo` is a public function, which returns anything you want - OS user name, application user name, application version etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I want the user name of the user logged in to the application using his application username which is stored in the access db  table itself..

Comment: So, you have a problem with retrieving user name, with storing to the table or with displaying this name to other users? I edited the answer a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for the help! answer you are provided can only be used in access 2007 as per my understanding ? I'm using access 2007

Comment: Data Macro not available in 2007, it was introduced in 2010. You can use AfterUpdate form's event though for inserting log information to the table.

Comment: @ Sergey S.  can you please provide an example